# MySQL left join where left table OR right table have conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select distinct places.*
from places
left join place_address on place_address.place_id = places.id 
left join addresses on place_address.address_id = addresses.id
left join cities on addresses.city_id = cities.id
where 
(places.description like '%Boston%' or cities.name = 'Boston')
and places.status = 1
order by places.name
```

It returns the correct results, but runs very slow. If I switch from "left join" to "join" it runs fast, but doesn't return results where "places.description" matches if there isn't an associated address. Is there a way to structure this to get the results I want and have it run quickly?

```
places Table
- id
- name
- description
- status

place_address Table
- place_id
- address_id

addresses Table
- id
- city_id

cities Table
- id
- name
```

I've seen similar questions about left joins where they suggest moving parts of the WHERE clause to the 'ON' condition, but that doesn't seem to work with an 'OR' condition for the left most and right most tables.

Comment: Have you tried checking the execution plan? It might point you to missing indices

Comment: This looks like a tuning problem to me, but the condition `where 
places.description like '%Boston%'` will preclude the use of an index, at least for the `places` table.

Comment: I haven't, I'll look into that, but all the 'id' fields are indices, and cities.name is also an index. I can break this into two queries and it runs fast, but I'd like to understand the correct way to structure it as a single query.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). In addition to the advice provided there, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query - although I would observe that `LIKE '%...' ` is a performance killer, although sometimes there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: The left join being slower than (inner) join is a natural thing - it needs to go through full index. I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with this query and I don't think there is a way of speeding left joins up to inner joins speed

Comment: ... but if there is a big mismatch in a number of places and number of addresses then there is nothing wrong in splitting the query and avoiding costly joins